# Reading text document in Android

Tags: android

How to display contents of a byte array using AlertDialog properly.  I've tried with below code

```
    try {
        FileInputStream in = m_context.openFileInput("Test.txt");
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        in.read(buf);
        in.close();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(m_context).setTitle("Alert").setMessage(buf.toString()).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
    } catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

what out i got displayed below

[image]

i think the value is memory address

please correct me

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have to use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

```
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line=reader.readLine();
```

Comment: your solution also works, thanks... i am a newbie and gained negative votes

Answer (score 1):

Construct String object:

```
new String(buf);
```

But that's going to have only first 1024 bytes of file.

Comment: @lxx hi you solution works, i need one more thing, received data's size is only 17 bytes, it shows huge alertdialog.  How can i trim string to received size

Comment: with new String(buf).trim(). If you're secure you will receive exactly 17 bytes, you could also initialize byte array with 17 instead of 1024.

Comment: @lxx size not define, it depends on receiving data

Comment: Use trim(). As far as the data is bellow 1024 bytes your approach will work. Otherwise you have to add a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method, put in the text file path in place of fileName. This method will read the text doument and return the string.

```
public String readTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    InputStream input            = assetManager.open(fileName);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.available());
    byte[] buffer                = new byte[512];
    int bytes;

    while ((bytes = input.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
    input.close();

    return new String(output.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[in this](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/14/how-to-readwrite-a-text-file-in-android/) you can find the code to read/write in a file a String. ‎

I hope it's helpful for you.